# XPC and cross-architecture OSX applications

Tags: objective-c, app-store, sandbox, xpc

for a desktop application I am developing, I have to stick with a 32-bit framework. I am looking for the best path to run the framework in its proper process and develop the rest of the application in a 64-bit process. The application is also meant to be sold in the AppStore, so it should support Apple sandboxing.

I am thinking about [XPC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html): is it suitable for these purposes? Why can't I find it in the Apple [documentation related to cross-architecture programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/Cross-ArchitecturePluginSupport/Cross-ArchitecturePluginSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001064-CH225-SW7)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> XPC: is it suitable for these purposes?

Yes, XPC should work correctly between 32-bit and 64-bit processes.

> Why can't I find it in the Apple documentation related to cross-architecture programming?

Because XPC is new in 10.7, and that 64-bit Transition Guide document is [rather old and hasn't been updated](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/revision_history/revision_history.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001064-CH223-SW1) since 10.6.  Apple is not always good at updating older documentation.